# How to prevent log poisoning for a REST service that accepts logs from the javascript clients

Tags: javascript, rest, security, jakarta-ee, spring-boot

How to prevent log poisoning for a REST service (Java/Spring Boot) that accepts logs from the Javascript (Angular 2) clients?

Legitimate clients should be able to make a POST to the REST URL.

The rest of the world should be prevented from make that POST call.

But I cannot think of how this can be achieved meaningfully. How can I distinguish legitimate clients from the rest of the world? Use some form of authentication? If so how does that look like?

Details:

Logging Service: It's a regular REST services with a mapping (endpoint) that accepts a log message and some related information through HTTP POST. Then intended use is that the Single Page Client applications (written in Angular, Angular 2, React and other js frameworks) can document any errors that are thrown in the browser (that can be seen in the DEV console) are properly sent back to this REST URL mapping (endpoint) so that we can see what errors users are seeing.

Clients: JS clients (Single page apps) using certain design principles will record the errors in javascript, collect them and make a POST call to the Logging service REST URL mapping.

The user may or may not be logged in. We (like everybody else) have unauthenticated pages as well as authenticated pages in the front end apps.

Comment: Please add a comment if you've down voted so that I can understand why and improve the question. Down voting without a comment makes it hard as I don't have any feedback.

Comment: I haven't downvoted your question. But maybe you can tell a bit more about your application. Are there other rest resources? Does the user have to login? Because actually you need some kind of authentication.

Comment: @R2C2 I have updated the questions with a few more details. Let me know if that should suffice.

Comment: Are there other rest resources? Does the user have to login? Because actually you need some kind of authentication.

Comment: @R2C2 Good question. But not necessarily. Even if the user is authenticated, he/she can still call the rest service, send fake data and perform log poisoning or misdirection. The advantage however for us is that we can identify and isolate the user. Another use case is that some pages can't have authentication (like registration pages). We still need to log JS errors on those pages right?

Answer (score 0):

For the given requirements: Sorry no chance.

Proof:

You want that your SPA can access the service but a user cannot forge a request. This means the service needs to distinguish legitimate requests from your SPA from illegitimate requests done manually.

So there has to be a legitimate request (otherwise there is no point in having a server). The legitimate request needs to be made by your SPA. An attacker can read the code of you SPA (which is always possible as it runs in the Browser) and gain the knowledge about how legitimate requests are constructed. Whatever secret there may be: it can be obtained. Now the attacker knows how a legitimate request looks like, he can construct it outside your app.

QED.

You can require all calls to be authenticated. Then you can pinpoint an attack to a specific user. But then of course there is no way to get any logs prior to authentication.

You might also want to check the sent logs for plausibility, i.e. validate the log format, do some rate limiting, etc.